# Android Studio with compileSdkVersion 16 don't compile on Mac

Tags: android, linux, macos, android-appcompat

I have used linux for a while, and now I'm on Mac.
I use Android Studio and I want to compile my old projects exported from Eclipse on linux. I have "repaired" gradle configuration to work on Mac, but I have some issues with compileSdkVersion setted on 16 (like I used on linux). My project give me some errors about appcompat-v7
Image link: (not sufficient points to post image) https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWj7f.jpg

When I set a bigger compileSdkVersion, it gives me about 5 errors, but I want to compile like on linux with version 16. What I need to do?
Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use AppCompat 23.0.1, you must compile with API 23.

Note that `compileSdkVersion` does not actually change any behavior in your app - that is what `targetSdkVersion` does.

Answer (score 0):

Check your compilesdk version. It needs to be >= to the support library version. E.g if you use appcompat version 7.23, then use compileSdkVersion 23